# Empty variable being used in code

Tags: java, android, logic, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm currently working my way through an online Udemy android course and came across this segment of code for a ListLoader

```
package com.kencephalon.friends;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FriendsListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Friend>> {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = FriendsListLoader.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<Friend> mFriends;
    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public FriendsListLoader(Context context , Uri uri, ContentResolver contentResolver){
        super(context);
        mContentResolver = contentResolver;
    }


    //Retrieves all the records
    public List<Friend> loadInBackground() {
        String[] projection = {BaseColumns._ID,
        FriendsContract.FriendsColumn.FRIENDS_NAME,
        FriendsContract.FriendsColumn.FRIENDS_PHONE,
        FriendsContract.FriendsColumn.FRIENDS_EMAIL};
        List<Friend> entries = new ArrayList<Friend>();

        mCursor = mContentResolver.query(FriendsContract.URI_TABLE,projection,null,null,null);

        if(mCursor != null){
            if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    int _id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                    String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(FriendsContract.FriendsColumn.FRIENDS_NAME));
                    String phone = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(FriendsContract.FriendsColumn.FRIENDS_PHONE));
                    String email = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(FriendsContract.FriendsColumn.FRIENDS_EMAIL));

                    Friend friend = new Friend(_id,name,phone,email);
                    entries.add(friend);
                }while (mCursor.moveToNext());


            }
        }
        return entries;

    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(List<Friend> friends) {


        if(isReset()){
            if(mFriends != null){
                mCursor.close();
            }
        }

        List<Friend> oldFriendsList = mFriends;
        if(mFriends == null || mFriends.size() == 0){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"+++++++++ No Data Returned");
        }
        mFriends = friends;
        if(isStarted()){
            super.deliverResult(friends);
        }
        if(oldFriendsList != null && oldFriendsList != friends ){
            mCursor.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if(mFriends != null){
            deliverResult(mFriends);
        }
        //Checks if the data has changed when the load was stopped or if there is no data and forces a reload
        if(takeContentChanged() || mFriends == null){
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        onStopLoading();
        if(mCursor != null){
            mCursor.close();
        }

        mFriends = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(List<Friend> friends) {
        super.onCanceled(friends);
        if(mCursor != null){
            mCursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void forceLoad() {
        super.forceLoad();
    }
}
```

The section of code starting from the overridden method deliverResult has me confused, particularly when the code is testing whether mFriends == null or mFriends.size() == 0.

As can be seen from the code sample, mFriends has only been declared at the very top with the following line

```
private List<Friend> mFriends;
```

and nothing more was done to it. Since this is the case, shouldn't mFriends be without a value, which would render the check

```
if(mFriends == null || mFriends.size() == 0){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"+++++++++ No Data Returned");
            }
```

pointless since the Log.d message would keep on getting logged every time the method deliverResult(0 is called since the if statement would keep returning true?

Furthermore, i do not see the reason in the code portion

```
if(oldFriendsList != null && oldFriendsList != friends ){
                mCursor.close();
            }
```

since oldFriendsList(with the value of mFriends) would then return true since mFriends would be equals to null.

As such, i also do not understand the method onStartLoading where the program checks if mFriends != null and calls deliverResult(mFriends), followed by checking if takeContentChanged() or if mFriends==null as shown in the following code extract since mFriends has been set to null by onReset()

```
protected void onStartLoading() {
            if(mFriends != null){
                deliverResult(mFriends);
            }
            //Checks if the data has changed when the load was stopped or if there is no data and forces a reload
            if(takeContentChanged() || mFriends == null){
                forceLoad();
            }
    }
```

QN:While i understand the the checks for mFriends == null is most likely due to the method onReset setting mFriends = null,which to my understanding happens whenever the loader(reset) is called for the first time and on subsequent reset() calls, **wouldn't the value of mFriends by always equal to null and will never be changed, which would render the whole code pointless?**

I have a feeling i'm missing something but i can't seem to figure out what exactly is it that i'm missing. Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this code written by someone else as an example to make you understand some concept?

Comment: @zulkarnain it's part of an app that is being built in a series of videos

Comment: Then I suppose those Log statements are clearly there for testing purposes.  Sometimes the developer writes testing code for a particular situation and then forgets to take it out from the final version.